# Networking with 2 VM and Bridged network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

ESXI VM : windows server 2016 (bridged network)

Within:

Guest OS1: windows server 2016 Setting: Adapter 1 attached to NAT (virtual box)

Guest OS2: Windows server 2012 Setting: Adapter 1 attached to NAT (virtual box)

Issue: can't ping from Birdged network to NAT VM

What is the required network setting i have to apply in virtual box VMS for networking the 3 VM together ??

I try to set the two virtual box vm in bridged network but the two vm cannot get the same ip subnet with bridged vm

this a diagram to more explain :

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0wzI.png)

how to allow the user (192.168.1.117) to access to the vm with Ip : 192.168.56.102

Comment: set up a small router VM with 2 NICs, one NAT and one internal/local.  All the other VMs are internal/local, and go through the router VM's interface.  Like this: https://smudj.wordpress.com/2019/01/23/setting-up-an-all-in-one-windows-ad-test-environment-vmware-workstation-edition/

Comment: Can't you fix IP for the two VMs in virtual box using the bridged network?   Can you ping **Guest OS1: windows server 2016** from **Guest OS2: Windows server 2012** when in the bridged network?

Comment: I would ping from bridged vm to the two guest OS1 et OS2